# Little coding challenge (Fermat’s Last Theorem)

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java; here is the exercise I am struggling with:

> Fermat’s Last Theorem says that there are no integers a, b, and c such that a^n + b^n = c^n except in the case when n = 2.
>
> Write a method named `checkFermat` that takes four integers as parameters— a, b, c and n—and that checks to see if Fermat’s theorem holds. If n is greater than 2 and it turns out to be true that a^n + b^n = c^n, the program should print “Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!” Otherwise the program should print “No, that doesn’t work.”
>
> You should assume that there is a method named `raiseToPow` that takes two integers as arguments and that raises the first argument to the power of the second. For example:
> `int x = raiseToPow(2, 3);`
> would assign the value 8 to x, because 2^3 = 8.

I have encountered several problems, for example I can't seem to use `Math.Pow(a, n)` with an `int`, only with a `double`. If you are interested, here is what I have so far, feel free to skip it and just write your own version of the program in the answers.

(Please keep in mind I started this book only a few days back.)

```
    package fermat.s_last_theorem;
    import java.lang.Math;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FermatS_Last_Theorem {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Inster First Number");
    double frst = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Insert Second Number");
    double scnd = s.nextDouble();
 
    System.out.println("Insert Exponent");
    double expo = s.nextDouble();


    double v =  FLaw(frst,scnd,expo);
    double k = FLawRes(v, expo);

    System.out.println("The answer is " + v);
    System.out.println("Your answer rooted by your exponent is " + k);
    Law(v, Pow(k, expo));
  
    
    }

    public static double Pow(double a, double b) {
    double res = Math.pow (a, b);
    return (res);
    }

    public static double FLaw(double frst, double scnd, double expo) {
    double D1 = Pow(frst, expo);
    double D2 = Pow(scnd, expo);
   
    
    return (D1 + D2);
    
     }
  
     public static double FLawRes(double res, double base) {
     
     double D3 = Pow(res, 1/base);
     return D3;
      }
     
     public static void Law(double v, double k) {
       if (v==k) {
     System.out.println("Pythagora works.");
      } else {
     System.out.println("Pythagora doesnt work");
    }
   }
 }
```

The main problem is that I am not exactly sure how to answer the question the exercise asks, and the program listed above does not work as it should.

Comment: You can use `(int) Math.Pow(a, n)` convert the returned value back into an integer.  (Assuming, of course, that you haven't exceeded the valid range of an integer.)

Comment: You are looking for the concept of "type casting."

Comment: You can read Java primitive type conversion，type casting and 
precision.

Comment: A key conditional is that it only involves integer exponents larger than 2.

Answer (score 3):

> You should **assume** that there is a method named raiseToPow ...

That means you write your code using such a method, even though you don't have the method. Your code will be reviewed manually, or teacher may supply the method and run your code.

If you want to test your code, you can always implement it yourself. You should just remove the method before turning in the code.

But the intent here is that this is a write-on-paper exercise.

---

Now, how to implement `int raiseToPow(int a, int b)`?

Think about what it means. 3<sup>4</sup> means 3 * 3 * 3 * 3.

So, implement the method to multiply by `a` by itself `b` times.

I'll leave that as another exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can break it out like this :

```
public boolean checkFermat(int a, int b, int c, int n) {
    if(n != 2 &&
      (checkFermatCondition(a,b,c,n) || 
       checkFermatCondition(a,c,b,n) || 
       checkFermatCondition(b,c,a,n))) {
         System.out.println("Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!");
    } else {
         System.out.println("No, that doesn’t work.");
    }
}
```

In this method you are just trying to reduce you check condition with all of the combinations by calling this method with different parameters

```
private boolean checkFermatCondition(int a, int b, int c, int n) {
    return raiseToPow(a,n)+raiseToPow(b,n) == raiseToPow(c,n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function raiseToPow()'s functionality can be achieved using [Math.pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println( "Fermat's Last Theorem: a^n+b^n != c^n (n!=2)"); 
    int a, b, c, n; 
    System.out.print("Enter value for a:"); 
    a = s.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("Enter value for b:"); 
    b = s.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("Enter value for c:"); 
    c = s.nextInt();
    while(true){
      System.out.print("Enter value for n:"); 
      n = s.nextInt();
      if(n!=2)
        break;
      System.out.println("n cannot be 2");
    }
    checkFremat(a,b,c,n);
  }

  public static void checkFremat(int a, int b, int c, int n){
    if ((int)Math.pow(a, n)+(int)Math.pow(b, n)!=(int)Math.pow(c, n)) 
      System.out.println("Fermat was correct!"); 
    else 
      System.out.println("Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!"); 
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/ErVl/1)